# Empty string position to return as *

Tags: c++, string

Very new to programming.
This bit of my program accepts two strand of DNA as input and output them in a double helix drawing. The problem is, if one of the two input strand is longer than the other, i will receive error.

So I thought, is it possible that if strand[add] is non-existent anymore, replace it with *?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
void helix(string &strand1, string &strand2)
{
    int nucleo;
    int length;
    if (strand1.length() >= strand2.length())
    {
        length = strand1.length();
    }
    else
    {
        length = strand2.length();
    }
    int add;
    for (int add = 0; add <= length - 1; add++)
    {
        if (add > 7)
        {
            nucleo = add % 8;
        }
        else
        {
            nucleo = add;
        }

        if (nucleo == 0)
        {
            cout << "     " << strand1[add] << "---"<<strand2[add] << endl;
        }

        else if (nucleo == 1)
        {
            cout << "    " << strand1[add] << "------" << strand2[add] << endl;
        }
        else if (nucleo == 2)
        {
            cout << "     " << strand1[add] << "------" << strand2[add] << endl;
        }
        else if (nucleo == 3)
        {
            cout << "       " << strand1[add] << "---" << strand2[add] << endl;
            cout << "         *" << endl;
        }
        else if (nucleo == 4)
        {
            cout << "       " << strand2[add]<<"---" << strand1[add] << endl;
        }
        else if (nucleo == 5)
        {
            cout << "     " << strand2[add]<<"------" << strand1[add] << endl;
        }
        else if (nucleo == 6)
        {
            cout << "    " << strand2[add]<<"------" << strand1[add] << endl;
        }
        else if (nucleo == 7)
        {
            cout << "     " << strand2[add]<<"-----" << strand1[add] << endl;
            cout << "       *" << endl;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    string strand1,strand2;

    cout << "ENTER STRAND:" << endl;
    cin >> strand1;
    cout << "ENTER STRAND:" << endl;
    cin >> strand2;
    helix(strand1,strand2);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I was hoping I could still show the longer strand even if the other side of the strand is empty(want to put *) like this :imgur.com/t7riVrS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you inverted the legnth test, it should be:

```
//if (strand1.length() >= strand2.length())
if (strand1.length() < strand2.length())
{
    length = strand1.length();
}
else
{
    length = strand2.length();
}
```

Edit:
If you want it fill one the string with '*', replace the code above with:

```
while (strand1.length() < strand2.length())
{
    strand1 += "*";
}
while (strand1.length() > strand2.length())
{
    strand2 += "*";
}
```

Comment: I was hoping I could still show the longer strand even if the other side of the strand is empty(want to put *) like this :http://imgur.com/t7riVrS

Comment: In that case, you can determine what is the shortest string and fill it with '*'